# Send Commands to Delphi Application with Lua Script

Tags: delphi, lua

I would like to be able to access TButton TCheckBox TEdit etc.. of a running Delphi application from a Lua script.
It is a retail Delphi application so I have no access to the source code. I would normally use AutoHotKey but would like more control.
Is this possible as I seem to be able to change things with the Enabler below. Could it be done by integrating Lua into a Delphi app and use it to send to the retail Delphi app ?
Or is there another way ? 
An open source solution would be best so to make it available to others.
I use Reaper DAW and it has API for Lua scripting I would like to be able to do similar with the Delphi app without the API available.

[image: Delphi Image]
[image: Delphi EDA]

Comment: If you want to remote control this delphi, have a look at AutoIt

Comment: Has AutoIt got any advantages over Autohokey that I was using ?

Comment: I have no experience with Autohotkey

Answer (score 1):

In order to run any script in a specific application then that specific application needs to have suitable scripting capabilities built into it in order to be able to interpret that script accordingly.

Now I'm guessing that "retail" application you are using doesn't have LUA scripting built into it otherwise you probably wouldn't be here.

So I'm afraid that the answer is no. You can't interact with a third part application from LUA script unless that application is designed to work with LUA scripts.

Comment: "Could it be done by integrating Lua into a Delphi app and use it to send to the retail Delphi app ?" So if it can't be done with Lua is there any other way of doing this as the Enabler, and EDA Preview software seems to be able to access and modify the Delphi.

Comment: Here is the EDA Delphi source code https://assarbad.net/de/stuff

Comment: See the EDA pic added above ^

Comment: I'm not familiar with EDA but it seems it is manipulating windows of windowed controls probably by using WinAPI functionality.